# Chrome not working, any idea?

Tags: css, keyframe

I want to create a spinning image using `CSS3`, but I don't know why it doesn't work on Chrome.
I tested with Firefox and IE, both working but not Chrome.
I just started learn about `@keyframe` in CSS3.
What is the mistake in my code?

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
.playing {
-webkit-animation-name: spin; 
-webkit-animation-duration: 1500ms;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-name: spin; 
-moz-animation-duration: 1500ms;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
-o-animation-name: spin; 
-o-animation-duration: 1500ms;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
-o-animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name: spin; 
animation-duration: 1500ms;
animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.playing:hover {
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
-moz-animation-play-state: paused;
-o-animation-play-state: paused;
animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the java script console in Developer Tools in chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
`-webkit-transform`
```

(instead of `transform`)

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/KvNr3/)**.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that `transform` need the `-webkit`, `-moz-`, and `-o-`. My careless instead...